# How to add text timed subtitles to view in MediaPlayerElement?

Tags: c#, uwp, mediaelement

I'm working on a UWP Desktop application for video editing and I need to include the subtitles feature. I've did what other questions recommend, but the TimedMetadataTracks list is still empty. Any help is most welcome.

XAML

```
<MediaPlayerElement x:Name="mediaPlayerElement" 
                                AutoPlay="False" 
                                Margin="5"
                                Width="640" Height="480"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" />
```

Code Behind

```
private void nviRestore_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create the media source and supplement with external timed text sources
        var source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/teste.mp4"));

        var ttsEnUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/en.srt");
        var ttsEn = TimedTextSource.CreateFromUri(ttsEnUri);
        ttsMap[ttsEn] = ttsEnUri;

        ttsEn.Resolved += Tts_Resolved;
        
        source.ExternalTimedTextSources.Add(ttsEn);
        
        // Create the playback item from the source
        var playbackItem = new MediaPlaybackItem(source);

        playbackItem.TimedMetadataTracksChanged += MediaPlaybackItem_TimedMetadataTracksChanged;

        
        // Set the source to start playback of the item
        this.mediaPlayerElement.SetPlaybackSource(playbackItem);

    }

    private void Tts_Resolved(TimedTextSource sender, TimedTextSourceResolveResultEventArgs args)
    {
        var ttsUri = ttsMap[sender];

        // Handle errors
        if (args.Error != null)
        {
            var ignoreAwaitWarning = Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                //rootPage.NotifyUser("Error resolving track " + ttsUri + " due to error " + args.Error.ErrorCode, NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            });
            return;
        }

        // Update label manually since the external SRT does not contain it
        var ttsUriString = ttsUri.AbsoluteUri;
        if (ttsUriString.Contains("_en"))
            args.Tracks[0].Label = "English";
    }

    private async void MediaPlaybackItem_TimedMetadataTracksChanged(MediaPlaybackItem sender, IVectorChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Present the first track
        sender.TimedMetadataTracks.SetPresentationMode(0, TimedMetadataTrackPresentationMode.PlatformPresented);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show some XAML?

Comment: @Stefan, I've included MediaPlayerElement XAML as well as Code Behind which adds Overlays to MediaComposition.

Comment: If you want to view subtitles on MediaElement, you could get an instance of TimedTextSource from [CreateFromUri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.timedtextsource.createfromuri?view=winrt-20348) method. After obtaining an instance, you can use it to set the MediaSource.ExternalTimedTextSources property of a MediaSource. You could find full sample [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/e13cf5dca497ad661706d150a154830666913be4/Samples/VideoPlayback/cs/Scenario4_DisplayingOutOfBandClosedCaptions.xaml.cs).

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT, I did what you recommended, but the subtitles is still not displayed. I edited the question to show everything that was done. If you can take a look, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I suggest you could check the subtitle file to see when it starts.